# angularjs directive to only allow alphabetic characters and numbers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been trying to implement a directive to restrict using of symbols such as

@,#,$,%,^,:),:D etc. i tried the following directive. It works but the first time i enter i can enter these symbols. Is there a more efficient directive that i can use.

This is the directive i used.

```
app.directive('onlyAlphabets', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
      function fromUser(text) {
        var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9a-z]/g, '');
        console.log(transformedInput);
        if(transformedInput !== text) {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
            ngModelCtrl.$render();
        }
        return transformedInput;
      }
      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
    }
  }; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the regex should be: `/[^0-9a-z]+/g`

Comment: i used that too. but it restricts those characters only when something is entered before.if the field is empty i can enter those characters.